# How can I query with association or collection object in MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

Here's my situation.

I have two class, say they are class A and class B. Class A has a reference with B, so when I try to get all columns in class A and class B, I'm using the association tag in MyBatis configuration, which looks like this.

```
<association property="b" column="id"
                 javaType="com.xx.B"
                 select="getBinfo"></association>
```

The configuration for getting the info for A:

```
<select id="list" parameterType="Map" resultMap="A">
    select * from A
</select>
```

The one for getting B info:

```
<select id="getBinfo" parameterType="Map" resultMap="B">
    select * from B where id = #{id}
</select>
```

It works fine getting all the columns into my bean, namely A here, with B info filled out correctly.

My question is, I can add `where` condition for `id="list"` to filter the result with the properties in A, what if I want to filter it with properties in B? How can I do it?

I'm trying to add `where` condition for `id="list"` with the columns in B, and passed the parameter with a `Map`. But the exception shows that the property is not set.

It's grateful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<association property="b" resultMap="bReusltMap" />
```

and join table b and add your where condition.